# java howto calculate Mbit/s during while loop download

Tags: java, performance, download

I have this `while` `loop` downloading a file

```
while ((val = bis.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0) {
   out.write(buffer, 0, val);
   fileSize -= val;
   if (fileSize < 1024) {
   val = (int) fileSize;
}
```

Trying to figure out how to show Mbit/s like many speed sites do.(link)
http://www.speedtest.net/
.

Would like the mesurment to stay inside the `while` loop but i have
seen examples using on-minute-threads firing but i dunno..

I dont know the amount of data, or the data is always 1024.
thats on of the problems i think
Any help is grate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I might be wrong by an order of magnitude or two, by the general idea is as follows:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
long totalRead = 0;
final double NANOS_PER_SECOND = 1000000000.0;
final double BYTES_PER_MIB = 1024 * 1024;

while ((val = bis.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0) {
    //...
    totalRead += val;
    double speedInMBps = NANOS_PER_SECOND / BYTES_PER_MIB * totalRead / (System.nanoTime() - start + 1);
    double speedInMbps = speed * 8;
}
```

Note that this calculates average speed from the beginning, not the current velocity.

Comment: what about this, should i just set it to 1000. cannot convert from double to float. final float NANOS_PER_SECOND = 1000000000.0;

Comment: change all floats to doubles then

Comment: nice i get this 0.5683736337 Mbit/s output. Im running Android phone on my LAN wifi to my computer over FTP. Maybe that is approximately half-a-MegaBit speed. how to verify that this is correct

Comment: One correction, this program outputs mega**bytes** per second, so 0,5 is actually around 4 Mbit/s.

Comment: @Erik: Yes, 4.5 Mbit/s it is.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz created a follow up question for anyone else doing this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157437/java-how-to-show-user-friendly-formatted-output-regarding-bandwidth-speed-during

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Hey tomas could you explain the meaning of your constants ? For isntance what is BYTES_PER_MIB ?And why do you do NANOS_PER_SECOND / BYTES_PER_MIB ? And also Why "+1" at the end of the speed formula ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that this loop is not executing on the UI thread. Declare two instance variables in your class:

```
volatile long totalDownloaded;
long downloadStartTime;
```

Modify your loop code as follows:

```
totalDownloaded = 0L;
downloadStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while ((val = bis.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0) {
   out.write(buffer, 0, val);
   totalDownloaded += val;
   fileSize -= val;
   if (fileSize < 1024) {
   val = (int) fileSize;
}
```

Schedule a task to run on the UI thread every so often that computes `System.currentTimeMillis() - downloadStartTime` and uses the elapsed time and the then-current value of `totalDownloaded` to compute the average download speed and update the display. You can do all this in a separate method in the same class:

```
/**
 * Returns average download speed in bytes/second.
 */
public float getDownloadSpeed() {
    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - downloadStartTime;
    return 1000f * totalDownloaded / elapsedTime;
}
```

Comment: maybe yea , btw everything is happening in an Android IntentService.class

Comment: @Erik - In order to interact with an activity, you might want to use a bound service instead of an IntentService.

Comment: the IntentService only display a Notification with Download progress in procent and now also with Mbit/s.

Comment: @TedHopp Hi, may I ask why do you multiply totalDownloaded by 1000?

Comment: @PhuNguyen - That's because `elapsedTime` is in milliseconds and the return value should be in units of bytes/second. To convert milliseconds to seconds, one divides by 1000. But since `elapsedTime` is in the denominator, this is equivalent to multiplying the return value by 1000. It could have been written `return totalDownloaded / (elapsedTime / 1000f);`.

Comment: @TedHopp Thanks for your kind explanation. I had a mistake in converting milliseconds into seconds.